# Sockets & File Descriptor Reuse (or lack thereof)

Tags: linux, networking, sockets, reusability, file-descriptor

I am getting the error "Too many open files" after the call to socket in the server code below. This code is called repeatedly, and it only occurs just after server_SD gets the value 1022. so i am assuming that i am hitting the limit of 1024 as proscribed by "ulimit -n". What i don't understand is that i am closing the Socket, which should make the fd reusable, but this seems not to be happening.

Notes: Using linux, and yes the client is closed also, no i am not a root user so moving the limits is not an option, I should have a maximum of 20 (or so) sockets open at one time. Over the lifetime of my program i would expect to open & close close to 1000000 sockets (hence need to reuse very strong).

```
  server_SD = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  
  bind (server_SD, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, server_len)  
  listen (server_SD,1)  
  client_SD = accept (server_SD, (struct sockaddr *)&client_address, &client_len)  
  // read, write etc...   
  shutdown (server_SD, 2);  
  close (server_SD)
```

Does anyone know how to guarantee closure & re-usability ?

Thanks.

Comment: What about the client socket?

Comment: yes the client is closed also...

Comment: The code looks okay.  What other file descriptors do you have open?  Somewhere, you've got 1022 file descriptors open.  During debugging, check the values returned by socket and figure out why they are increasing.  That is, examine the calls to open, fopen, pipe, popen, etc. that are you making between the calls to socket.

Comment: for this, btw, `strace` is your friend

Comment: Are you actually closing client_SD anywhere?

Comment: The only other files i am opening are on shutdown, (but its crashing well before getting there!) The only fds that are manipulated during general processing are the ones for the sockets. 

socket appears to be returning the lowest free descriptor, correctly, its why the descriptors are not free that is the issue.

Comment: yes MarkR, the client is closed also..

Comment: @Nigel, please edit to show the smallest possible, but complete, code that reproduces your symptoms, even if you have to fake the external clients with `netcat(1)`.  William's comment is quite right, and there's not enough context to give a confident answer.

Comment: i am busy extracting the client server stuff to see it in isolation, if this doesn't provide a fix, ill post the complete code here. 

N.

Comment: @Nigel: You need to close client_SD *in the server process*.  This is the server's connection to the client.  That is not the same as closing the client.

Comment: yes, in the server process : 

  result = close (server_SD);
  if (result == -1) {
    printf ("Server %d, ID %d, close server Failed\n", key);
    perror ("close server ");
  }
  result = close (client_SD);
  if (result == -1) {
    printf ("Server %d, ID %d, close client Failed\n", key);
    perror ("close client ");
  }

Comment: ... or does the _order_ of closing matter ???

Comment: Yes, that was the problem... One needs to close the client before closing the server (reverse order to my code above!)

Thanks all who offered suggestions !

Answer (score 3):

Run your program under `valgrind` with the `--track-fds=yes` option:

```
valgrind --track-fds=yes myserver
```

You may also need `--trace-children=yes` if your program uses a wrapper or it puts itself in the background.

If it doesn't exit on its own, interrupt it or kill the process with "`kill` *pid*" (*not* `-9`) after it accumulates some leaked file descriptors.  On exit, `valgrind` will show the file descriptors that are still open and the stack trace corresponding to where they were created.

Running your program under `strace` to log all system calls may also be helpful.  Another helpful command is `/usr/sbin/lsof` `-p` *pid* to display all currently used file descriptors and what they are being used for.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it looks like you are opening server socket for each `accept(2)`. That is not necessary. Create server socket once, `bind(2)` it, `listen(2)`, then call `accept(2)` on it in a loop (or better yet - give it to `poll(2)`)

#### Edit 0:

By the way, `shutdown(2)` on listening socket is totally meaningless, it's intended for connected sockets only.

Comment: Correct, i am opening the server socket for each accept. However it is not possible to reorganize my program this way, i need to maintain a strict 1:1 coupling between ports and servers. Besides, this doesn't explain why the fd is failing to be freed.

Comment: Are you binding that server socket to different port every time?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your problem is that you're not specifying the SO_REUSEADDR flag?

From the [socket](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket) manpage:

> SO_REUSEADDR
>       Indicates that the rules used in validating addresses supplied in a bind(2) call should allow reuse of local addresses. For PF_INET sockets this means that a socket may bind, except when there is an active listening socket bound to the address. When the listening socket is bound to INADDR_ANY with a specific port then it is not possible to bind to this port for any local address.

Comment: Yes i am using "SO_REUSEADDR" : 

  int yes = 1;
  setsockopt(server_SD,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&yes,sizeof(int));

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `fork()`?  if so, your children may be inheriting the opened file descriptors.
If this is the case, you should have the child close any fds that don't belong to it.

Comment: no, not using fork. my client processes are spawned using a system call, and are not inheriting anything from the server/parent.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you might have a "TIME_WAIT" problem. IIRC, TIME_WAIT is one of the status a TCP socket can be in, and it's entered when both side have closed the connection, but the system keeps the socket for a while, to avoid delayed messages to be accepted as proper payload for subsequent connections.

You shoud maybe have a look at [this](http://books.google.fr/books?id=X-Ah8PusbZkC&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=tcp+socket+time+wait&source=bl&ots=fH7RPW3Vtr&sig=_I6RzasOvhldI-0W9CjUvovpvg0&hl=fr&ei=XWx5SuabJOehjAfnkeSnBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=5#v=onepage&q=tcp%20socket%20time%20wait&f=false) (bottom of page 99 and top of 100). And maybe that [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41602/how-to-forcibly-close-a-socket-in-timewait).

Comment: i have used :  
  setsockopt(server_SD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_LINGER, &l, sizeof (l));  
with l set to 0.

so no, the socket should not linger.

Also, a look at netstat tells me that the connections are going away quickly, but 'ls /proc/<pid>/fd' tells me that the file descriptors are not being released.

Comment: TIME_WAIT sockets should not consume file descriptors if they have been closed by the process(es) which own them.

Comment: Use SO_REUSEADDR instead of SO_LINGER unless you understand _exactly_ what both options do.

Comment: I Believe i do, Are you saying they should not be used concurrently ?

Answer (score -1):

One needs to close the client before closing the server (reverse order to my code above!)
Thanks all who offered suggestions !