# Is there an upper limit for socket connections?

Tags: linux, network-programming

I am using the timeout mechanism to close my connection socket, which will close inactive connections greater than 15s. But my Linux system seems to only allow me to create 1024 sockets in the same time period.

So I want to ask

(1) Is there a connection limit for the connection socket?

(2) If there is an upper limit, is the timeout mechanism unable to resist a large number of concurrent requests in the same time period?

(3) I am using a dual-core 4g virtual machine. Will improving the configuration increase the number of its creation?

(4) If (2) is correct, what method (or how long) should the server use to close the socket?

Comment: You may want to focus this more, it is currently 4 separate questions that may be loosely related.

Comment: Sounds like if you run `ulimit -n` it will be reporting 1024.

Comment: Yes, this makes it difficult for me to test a large number of concurrent requests.

Comment: Increase it will allow more. But that is simply question 1. Your question 2, 3, and 4 are different questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1232482/8864226

Comment: Thank you for your comment, which is very helpful to me. In fact, I found that my problem may be related to long connections and short connections, and I will continue to learn them.